# Use JQ to extract an array of paths and also replace those values by it own path

Tags: bash, path, jq

Idk if JQ is able to do it in an easy way, but I would like to ask the experts here before moving to another tool.

I will receive an array with JSON paths that need to be extracted.

Those selected keys and their values, will generate a property file, and also  be replaced in the JSON itself.

Example:

INPUT ARGS: "description" "assets.url"
**^^^ we can change this INPUT format to assets[].url if it makes easier to handle arrays ^^^**

JSON:

```
 {
        "title": "TEST TITLE",
        "description": "TEST DESCRIPTION",
        "type": "Promo",
        "assets": [{
           "content_type": "image",
           "url": "https://www.fakesite.com/image.jpg"
           }, {
           "content_type": "image",
           "url": "https://www.fakesite.com/image2.jpg"
        }]
    }
```

Expected OUTPUT:

1) a property file (key=value)

```
description=TEST DESCRIPTION
assets_0_url=https://www.fakesite.com/image.jpg
assets_1_url=https://www.fakesite.com/image2.jpg
```

2) a transformed JSON file

```
 {
        "title": "TEST TITLE",
        "description": "${description}",
        "type": "Promo",
        "assets": [{
           "content_type": "image",
           "url": "${assets_0_url}"
           }, {
           "content_type": "image",
           "url": "${assets_1_url}"
        }]
    }
```

The OUTPUT keys (in this case: description, assets_0_url, assets_1_url) don't need to follow this format, but it needs to be numbered and unique in case of arrays.

The only requirement is that the OUTPUT property file's keys matches with the replaced values in the OUTPUT JSON.

PROPERTY:

**description**=TEST DESCRIPTION

JSON:

"description": "**${description}**",

What I made so far:

```
FIELDS="description\|assets.*url"
OUTPUT=$(jq -r 'paths(scalars) as $p | "\($p|join("_"))=\(getpath($p))"' $FILE | grep $FIELDS)
printf "%s\r" "$OUTPUT" > json.properties
```

Which gives me the following json.properties file:

```
description=TEST DESCRIPTION
assets_0_url=https://www.fakesite.com/image.jpg
assets_1_url=https://www.fakesite.com/image2.jpg
```

Is that possible with JQ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason for the specific properties file format you give here, or is *any* way to use content from one JSON file to fill out a different one acceptable?

Comment: (While either approach is *possible*, it would be a lot easier to make your input file that contains `"url": "${assets_0_url}"` instead contain `"url": .assets[0].url` -- which is to say, to have that input be jq source code instead of JSON itself; then you don't need the intermediate properties format at all).

Comment: ...or is (3) sample output, meaning you want to map *values* back to *keys*? That's doable too, but if it's what you intend, then the question should probably be edited for clarity to make it explicit.

Comment: Hi, I can change the input to any format, whatever is easier, I just need extract those values to a property file (I dont need to follow a Key name pattern also, but I need to make sure the arrays are numbered and unique), and those extracted JSON values need to be replaced by the same key name pattern from the property file. Idk if I was able to clarify lol,  thank you

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to explicitly label which code samples are inputs and which are outputs, and which specific components can be changed and which can't? At one point the question text says that the properties are input; but if that's true, the statement that the input can be changed to any format and the statement that a properties file (and not any other format) must be used are in conflict with each other.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I tried to make it clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following addresses the bulk of the requirements but leaves the parsing of the "INPUT ARGS" as an exercise.

### Property File

```
def propertyValue(property):
  "\(property)=\(.[property])";

def propertyValue(arrayvaluedproperty; property):
  .[arrayvaluedproperty] as $a
  | range(0; $a|length) as $i
  | "\(arrayvaluedproperty)_\($i)_\(property)=\($a[$i][property])";

propertyValue("description"),
propertyValue("assets"; "url")
```

### Transformed JSON

```
def updateProperty(p):
  .[p] = "${\(p)}";

def updateProperty(arrayvaluedproperty; p):
  .[arrayvaluedproperty] as $a
  | reduce range(0; $a|length) as $i (.;
    .[arrayvaluedproperty][$i] = "${\(arrayvaluedproperty)_\($i)_\(p)}");


updateProperty("description")
| updateProperty("assets"; "url")
```